# Currency input mask with cents for masked edit

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to set an input mask for Infragistics Ultramaskededit. It has `.Mask` property (string). I have tried `"999,999.00"` but this cut cents and `"###,###.##"` but this lead to exception.

I have found solution - `"#########.##"` this is mask and `Type` of the box must be set to `double` - all works.

Comment: Which 'third party maskedtextbox'?

Comment: winforms, wpf, sl, web, winrt?

Comment: winforms - the mask As I understood must be passed as argument string

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
textBox.Mask = "c"
```

Comment: sorry, could you support me with sample? I have tryed "999,999,999.99" and this excepted too(